# In-app purchasing in xamarin.android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, in-app-billing

I want to add in-app purchase in my app. but some how, for xamarin, I could not find any proper solution.

I have tried the following :

1. I found [this](https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.inappbilling?version=1.1) component. but webpage is unavailable when I try to 
   download it. And no nuget package I found in the nuget package manager.
2. [this](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3) package is also not available for xamarin.
3. I also could not find `Google Play Billing Library` in SDK manager.So that I could try `Billing Client` or something they have mentioned in [this link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_java_kotlin#java)

One more question, 
what is the process if I only want it for testing ? and process for actual purchase ? for the testing purpose I need to submit my signed apk on Developer Console?

Thank you!

Comment: You could try to read this blog : [Integrating In-App Purchases in Mobile Apps](https://blog.xamarin.com/integrating-in-app-purchases-in-mobile-apps/)

Comment: @Billy, I tried this plugin but it says 'context/activity is null' MainApplication.cs is not created in my project.

Comment: When I try to connect using ConnectAsync method above error occurs